# How to generate html Docs for openapi components schema files

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, redoc, redocly

Here is the file structure. And I would like to generate html documentation for `components/schemas/..` not for `openapi.yaml` which has endpoints.

```
├── code samples
│   └── C#
│       └── postundefined
│   └── PHP
│       └── postundefined
├── components
│   └── headers
│       └── ExpiresAfter.yaml
│   └── responses
│       └── Problem.yaml
│   └── schemas
│       └── Email.yaml
│       └── Problem.yaml
│       └── Schema.yaml
│       └── User.yaml
├── paths
│       └── echo.yaml
│       └── pathItem.yaml
│       └── pathItemWithExamples.yaml
│       └── users@{username}.yaml
└── openapi.yaml
```

Here is a git hub page [openapi-starter](https://github.com/Redocly/openapi-starter). It has a folder structure `components/schemas/..`

Using [redocly](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/) `redocly build-docs openapi.yaml` it generates it only generate `redoc-static.html` and it has all the documentation for rest endpoints but not for schemas.

In my case, I would like to generate documentation/html pages only for the schemas and in this particular case `Email.yaml`, `User.yaml`, `Schema.yaml`, `User.yaml`

Is there any tool that can accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

I went down this path as well and found that it is not possible currently.

There is a premium docs paid feature which allows you to generate the schema views but only as a `preview-docs` command, not `build-docs`.

In order to generate static html with schemas shown separately that you can host on your own site, you'd have to pay for the enterprise edition of Redocly.

Link to github issue here:
https://github.com/Redocly/redocly-cli/issues/1015

Comment: Hi James, 

Thanks for sharing it. Also ended up at the same place :D